# Is wind and string instruments haram to build, listen to, or play with?

Tags: halal-haram, source-identification, music

I would like to know where can I find the Hadith in which it mentions that wind and string instruments are prohibited? and if the hadith is authentic or not? and What is the reason for this prohibition?

I heard from someone that it was prohibited because in the Prophet's (May Allah's peace and blessings be upon Him) day, they used to kill animals to make these instruments, is this the main reason? if not, than what is the reason?

I would also like to know if there are any opinions of reliable scholars on this as well.

Comment: Playing or making? Or both?

Comment: @Noah both, as well as listening to them

Comment: Also how about music generated without instruments like Dubstep for example, would it also be haram

Answer (score 1):

Please go to this link http://www.islamicstudies.info/literature/halal-haram/halal-haram.php?id=16 . According to the writer, Singing and Music are permitted as long as it doesn't make you indifferent about your religious obligations and certain conditions are met.

On the other hand, go to this link http://www.inter-islam.org/Prohibitions/Mansy_music.htm . It cites Music and Singing as Haraam in any cases.

There is a hadith where the Prophet (SAW) cits stringed instruments in line with fornication and drinking.

I'm still searching for the right answer as this seems a very controversial issue as there is no direct verse against stringed instruments.

Allah knows best. May He guide us to the right path.

Adnan

Comment: The issue is controversial because there's no clear-cut evidence to prove music is haraam.  That should be enough proof to say it's allowed.

Comment: That is not a proof that it is allowed. There is a Hadith that states "Halal is mentioned. Haram is mentioned. In Between them are grey areas, whoever goes there, may soon fall into haram." The wording may be different but the idea is conveyed here. If a topic is controversial to such an extent that Ulama call it Haram while some disagree, we can say this is a grey area. But hey, I do not agree that music is allowed. It has been proven by multiple hadiths that its haram and I will post them when I get enough time. A hadith clearly states that people in later years will make haram halal.